# Given that the Current SendGrid Nuget package is broken, how Can I tell teamCity to use the version I have specified

Tags: c#, teamcity, nuget-package-restore

Currently sendgrid nuget package (c#) 9.12.5 is broken and is not signed correctly, therefore in my visual studio solution I downgraded my version to 9.12.1, My solution works locally. However, when I deploy my Team City is "Helpful" and uses the latest version regardless of what I have done. So my question is How do I stop team city from installing the later (broken) version.

I have looked and I cant see anything obvious in my Restore packages step? Anybody know how to do this in team city?

Regards Julian

Comment: I have checked the .csproj file and the packages.config and they are both 9.12.1, team city is fetching 9.12.5

Answer (score 0):

Ok, its not obvious but the Update via Nuget tick box is the problem, the comments are not specific and dont tell you that this will install beyond the version you have specified. So Ok - unticking that got it to use the version I needed. This is here for anybody else who gets tripped up by this unclear switch in teamcity.